# c1-c2 regular expression in sed and grep

Tags: sed, grep, regular-expression, command

I'm trying to understand what the expression `[c1-c2]` does when used with `sed` or `grep`:

```
grep -E "[c1-c2]"
```

This matches 1-9 and a, b, c. As I understand it, it should match the characters between 1 and c in the ASCII table.

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by `[c1-c2]`. Do you mean the character class consisting of the characters between the character `c1` and `c2`, e.g. `[d-q]`, or do you mean the literal character class `[c1-c2]`?  If you have seen this anywhere, then a reference to that text would also be helpful.

Answer (score 7):

`[c1-c2]` is a [bracket expression](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696699/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html#tag_09_03_05). In the form given, it matches the character ”c”, the range of characters between “1” and “c” inclusive, and the character ”2”. The range of characters depends on the locale; [in the POSIX locale](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696699/basedefs/xbd_chap07.html#tag_07_03_02_06), it’s the set of characters whose ASCII code is between 49 (the code for “1”) and 99 (the code for “c”). Thus:

```
$ echo : | LANG=C grep -E '[c1-c2]'
:
$ echo 0 | LANG=C grep -E '[c1-c2]'
$ echo A | LANG=C grep -E '[c1-c2]'
A
```

I suspect the intention was that `c1` and `c2` represent individual characters which bound the range you’re interested in, so you’d write `[a-m]` or something like that, not `[c1-c2]`.

Answer (score 4):

In locales other than POSIX/C, the character ranges don't use the ASCII order but the collation sequence for the locale. These are typically more complicated than the ASCII order. [The standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/xrat/V4_xbd_chap09.html#tag_21_09_03_05) makes the interpretation of character ranges rather undefined (read: application dependent), but given than many locales differentiate uppercase and lowercase, it makes sense to decompose `1-c` as:

- `1-` from "1" to the end of its group (ie, numbers from `1` to `9`...)
- `-c` the beginning the lowercase group, up to `c`

(this also excludes the punctuation characters).

So in my locale `[1-c]` is the same as... `[123456789aàâäbc]`! (with possibly even more variants of 'a' than my keyboard supports):

```
grep -Eo '[c1-c2]+' <<< '01234àâäbc'
1234àâäbc
```

And `[c1-c2]` of course, matches the same thing since the list above already contains `c` and `2`.